# Android Dropbox Core API...read content of text file

Tags: android, file, dropbox

this is my first post here I wish the next one is to help somebody and to ask...

I am facing a problem with Dropbox core API.
I am working on an application where the user will be able to choose a text file and the app takes the file's content and uses it...
Can anybody help me and tell me how I can get the content? I searched alot for that but still cant find anything...

First the app authenticates the user and asks for permissions:

```
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();

if (mDBApi.getSession().authenticationSuccessful()) {
    try {
        // Required to complete auth, sets the access token on the session
        mDBApi.getSession().finishAuthentication();

        String accessToken = mDBApi.getSession().getOAuth2AccessToken();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.i("DbAuthLog", "Error authenticating", e);
    }
}
```

Then the programm uses the dropbox chooser to prompt the user to choose a file:

```
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import com.dropbox.chooser.android.DbxChooser;

    static final int DBX_CHOOSER_REQUEST = 0;  // You can change this if needed

    private Button mChooserButton;
    private DbxChooser mChooser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mChooser = new DbxChooser(APP_KEY);

        mChooserButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chooser_button);
        mChooserButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mChooser.forResultType(DbxChooser.ResultType.PREVIEW_LINK)
                        .launch(MainActivity.this, DBX_CHOOSER_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == DBX_CHOOSER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            DbxChooser.Result result = new DbxChooser.Result(data);
            Log.d("main", "Link to selected file: " + result.getLink());

            // Handle the result
        } else {
            // Failed or was cancelled by the user.
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

The app gets the file name and link correctly. How can I copy the content and save it to a string variable?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using a mix of the Core API and the Chooser. You're authenticating a user, but I don't see any calls to the Core API at all. It looks like so far you're just using the Chooser. Once you have a URL, you can just download the contents the same way you would fetch the contents of any URL.

The idea of the Chooser is that you don't need to authenticate a user at all, so if this is all you need to do, you can get rid of the code that authenticates a user (and stop linking the Core SDK in your app).

If you want to use the Core API, check out the tutorial: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android